# Strange behaviour: Java Comparator randomizes list entries

Tags: java, blackberry, list

I'm curious. What could be the reason that a Comparator shuffles entries on each 
application start?

```
final static class ContactsListComparator implements Comparator
{                           
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2)
    {
        if((o1.toString().compareTo(o2.toString()))<0)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        if((o1.toString().compareTo(o2.toString()))>0)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }    
}
```

First App Start:

[image]

Second App Start

[image]

As mentioned in one the answer

The Comparator actually compares an custom object Contact

```
public class Contact 
{
  // Members
  private String _contactFirstName;
  private String _contactLastName;
  private long _contactLastModified;

// Constructor
public Contact()
{
    set_contactLastModified();
}

public Contact(String contactFirstName)
{
    _contactFirstName = contactFirstName;
    set_contactLastModified();
}

// Accessable Getters
public String get_contactFirstName() 
{
    return _contactFirstName;
}

public String get_contactLastName()
{
    return _contactLastName;
}

public long get_contactLastModified()
{
    return _contactLastModified;
}

public void set_contactLastModified()
{
    _contactLastModified = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
  }
```

Comment: more code is needed. How did you use this comparator ?

Comment: I would take a close look at what the toString() method does. It may, for example, just list a serial id of the object.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

your toString method probably isn't overridden for your objects representing the contacts. It will return a hash string for those objects, which varies every time your app is run.

You can fix this either of two ways:

- Override the `toString()` method in your `Contact` object to return the contact's name (1), or
- Change the `Comparator` to `Comparator<Contact>` so it gets `Contact` objects as parameters (2)

for (1), add this to your Contact class:

```
@Override public String toString() {
    return get_contactFirstName();
}
```

for (2) you would end up with this Comparator implementation:

```
final static class ContactsListComparator implements Comparator<Contact> {                           
    public int compare(Contact o1, Contact o2) {
        return contact1.get_contactFirstName().compareTo(contact2.get_contactFirstName());
    }
}
```

you don't even need to check for the <0 or >0, but you can just return whatever the String comparison gives.

Comment: correct! =) ((ContactsListObject)o1).get_contactFirstName().compareTo(((ContactsListObject)o2).get_contactFirstName())

Answer (score 2):

I would use:

```
final static class ContactsListComparator implements Comparator<Contact>
{
public int compare(Contact c1,Contact c2)
 {
 int i=c1.get_contactLastName().compareTo(c2.get_contactLastName());
 if(i!=0) return i;
 return c1.get_contactFirstName().compareTo(c2.get_contactFirstName());;
 }

}
```

Comment: Comparator<Contact> needs a least JRE 1.5, doesn't it?

Comment: they won't work in J2ME though - gotta stick to ugly casting!

Answer (score 2):

Your first example is basically the same as

```
final static class ContactsListComparator implements Comparator {                           
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        return o1.toString().compareTo(o2.toString());
    }    
}
```

This would work if you override toString() like

```
public String toString() {
     return _contactFirstName + ' ' + _contactLastName;
}
```

However, a comparator which compares the intended fields is better as has been suggested.